# Closely-spaced datalabels are hidden

Tags: highcharts

Some datalabels in my [barchart](http://jsfiddle.net/L0zgL9kr/) aren't shown: Only one datalabel is shown at the categories "Wohnung Zustand", "Wohnumfeld" and "Wohn- und Nebenkosten".

My current solution is to chose a [smaller font-size](http://jsfiddle.net/L0zgL9kr/1/)

```
dataLabels: {
  style: {
    fontSize: '7pt',
    fontFamily: '"Tahoma"',
    fontWeight: 'normal'
  }
```

but now the label is hard to read. I'd like to have a bigger font-size and overlapping labels, but my overflow and crop-settings don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [allowOverlap](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.dataLabels.allowOverlap)-setting: the [chart with overlapping datalabels](http://jsfiddle.net/L0zgL9kr/2/)..

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  allowOverlap: true,
}
```